# Access Query: Values disappear when I name/alias my expression the same as the inherited field

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a query that's pulling data from another. Here's my SELECT statement in SQL:

```
SELECT
    [Orders].Date,
    [Orders].[Part Number],
    [Orders].Region
```

Using this, my column headers read as follows:

```
  Date  ||  [Orders].[Part Number]  ||     Region
  12/1  ||         AAA001           ||  North America
  12/1  ||         BBB002           ||  North America
  12/1  ||         CCC003           ||  North America
```

Note the fact that **Date** and **Region** are labelled as one word, while **Part Number** has the Form/Field format. To try and avoid this, I add an alias.

```
SELECT
    [Orders].Date,
    [Orders].[Part Number] AS [Part Number],
    [Orders].Region
```

When I do this my header appears normally, but all of my values disappear:

```
  Date  ||  Part Number  ||     Region
  12/1  ||               ||  North America
  12/1  ||               ||  North America
  12/1  ||               ||  North America
```

If I name it *anything else* (even if I just add an "s" at the end to make "Part Number**s**"), the values re-appear.

```
  Date  ||  Part Numbers  ||     Region
  12/1  ||     AAA001     ||  North America
  12/1  ||     BBB002     ||  North America
  12/1  ||     CCC003     ||  North America
```

---

Anyone know where I can start looking to try and fix this?

**Edit** Here's my full query. I guess here I should note that the first three fields are pulled from a Union query, if that matters. Names were changed for simplicity above, but now they're their actual names. The problem I'm having with is [uQuery Forecast/Orders].[Part Number].

```
SELECT 
    [uQuery Forecast/Orders].Date, 
    [uQuery Forecast/Orders].[Part Number], 
    [uQuery Forecast/Orders].Region, 
    Val(IIf(IsNull([Orders].[QTY]),0,[Orders].[QTY])) AS [Order QTY], 
    Val(IIf(IsNull([Forecast].[QTY]),0,[Forecast].[QTY])) AS [Forecast QTY], 
    Val(IIf(IsNull([Builds].[QTY]),0,[Builds].[QTY])) AS [Build QTY]
FROM (([uQuery Forecast/Orders] 
    LEFT JOIN [Orders] ON 
        ([uQuery Forecast/Orders].[Part Number] = [Orders].[Part Number]) AND
        ([uQuery Forecast/Orders].[Date] = [Orders].[Date])) 
    LEFT JOIN [Forecast] ON 
        ([uQuery Forecast/Orders].[Part Number] = [Forecast].[Part Number]) AND
        ([uQuery Forecast/Orders].[Date] = [Forecast].[Date])) 
    LEFT JOIN [Builds] ON 
        ([uQuery Forecast/Orders].Date = [Builds].[Date]) AND
        ([uQuery Forecast/Orders].[Part Number] = [Builds].[Part Number])
GROUP BY 
    [uQuery Forecast/Orders].Date, 
    [uQuery Forecast/Orders].[Part Number], 
    [uQuery Forecast/Orders].Region, 
    Val(IIf(IsNull([Orders].[QTY]),0,[Orders].[QTY])), 
    Val(IIf(IsNull([Forecast].[QTY]),0,[Forecast].[QTY])), 
    Val(IIf(IsNull([Builds].[QTY]),0,[Builds].[QTY]));
```

---

**EDIT 2**

Here's my Union Query. It's only purpose is to list any and all unique combinations of Date ↔ Part Number ↔ Region. I only have 3 regions, and ~1000 part numbers. The date starts at 9/1/17, so even after 20 years there's only be 7305 entries. All together, that's a maximum of 22,000,000 rows.

```
SELECT 
    [Orders].[Date] AS [Date], 
    [Orders].[Part Number] AS [Part Number], 
    [Orders].[Region] AS [Region]
FROM [Orders]
UNION SELECT 
    [Forecast].[Date], 
    [Forecast].[Part Number], 
    [Forecast].[Region]
FROM [Forecast]
UNION SELECT 
    [Builds].[Date], 
    [Builds].[Part Number], 
    [Builds].[Region]
FROM [Builds];
```

Comment: Renaming a column should never affect the values in the column (unless the name conflicts with an existing column in the result set).

Comment: Indeed, likely, you are joining other tables with same field name. Post **entire** query.

Comment: @Parfait Full SQL added. Note, I had changed the names for simplicity, but now they're their actual names.

Comment: I'm curious.  Does the same behavior happen if you do the same thing to the 'Date' field?  In other words, is it weird behavior that only happens for a field with a space in it?  Likewise, have you tried changing the GROUP BY clause to reference the new column name instead of the [Query Source].[Column Name]?  Just wild stabs in the dark for some stuff to try - I'm currently mystified as to what might be going on.

Comment: I mean, I could easily see this being "MS-Access Bug" territory, instead of "Bad Query" territory.  How often do people take column names with spaces, and then rename the column to the exact same column name?

Comment: `GROUP BY` seems unnecessary in this query, since there is no aggregation occurring in the `SELECT`. Does removing it work?

Comment: @Kevin The same thing does not happen if I alias "[Date]" or "[Region]", no. Turns out the Group By is unnecessary, but removing it doesn't fix it.

Comment: @ChrisMeurer You're right, it's unnecessary. However, removing it doesn't fix things.

Comment: ... and just to make sure, you're trying to rename it to the same thing, including the space?  As in: [Orders].[Part Number] AS [Part Number],  ?

Comment: @Kevin Yes, that's correct. Without the alias, the values appear. With "AS [Part Number]", they disappear. And to confirm, only the part numbers disappear. There's still an equal amount of rows, and the other cells are populated.

Comment: Do you have any `NULL` values for `[Part Number]` in the result set of your `UNION` query?

Comment: @ChrisMeurer I do not. All fields are populated. The Union query simply pulls direct values from `[Orders]`, `[Forecast]`, and `[Builds]` to get unique combinations, and there's no `NULL` values there either.

Answer (score 1):

Your SQL maintains three underlying tables each with *Part Number* fields: *Orders*, *Forecasts*, and *Builds*. Consequently, in outer query there is a named clash and Access shows the table name qualified by period in query's column name. Same issue would appear for *Date* and *QTY* had you included them in outer query's `SELECT`.

To resolve consider using column aliases in underlying tables to change original *Part Numbers* and use those names in `ON` clauses. See adjusted query using derived tables and also uses table aliases. You can also save those nested `SELECT` as their own queries and referenced them here.

```
SELECT 
    u.Date, 
    u.[Part Number], 
    u.Region, 
    Val(IIf(IsNull(o.[QTY]), 0, o.[QTY])) AS [Order QTY], 
    Val(IIf(IsNull(f.[QTY]), 0, f.[QTY])) AS [Forecast QTY], 
    Val(IIf(IsNull(b.[QTY]), 0, b.[QTY])) AS [Build QTY]
FROM (([uQuery Forecast/Orders] u
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT [Part Number] As [O_Part_Number], [QTY], [Date] FROM [Orders]) o 
      ON  (u.[Part Number] = o.[O_Part Number]) 
      AND (u.[Date] = o.[Date])) 
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT [Part Number] As [F_Part_Number], [QTY], [Date] FROM [Forecast]) f
      ON  (u.[Part Number] = f.[F_Part_Number])
      AND (u.[Date] = f.[Date])) 
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT [Part Number] As [B_Part_Number], [QTY], [Date] FROM [Builds]) b 
      ON  (u.[Part Number] = b.[B_Part_Number])
      AND (u.[Date] = b.[Date]) 
GROUP BY 
    u.Date, 
    u.[Part Number], 
    u.Region, 
    Val(IIf(IsNull(o.[QTY]), 0, o.[QTY])), 
    Val(IIf(IsNull(f.[QTY]), 0, f.[QTY])), 
    Val(IIf(IsNull(b.[QTY]), 0, b.[QTY]));
```

Comment: As above, the `GROUP BY` clause serves no purpose here.

Comment: You're going to love this... Your code has no errors, but my column header reads `u.Part Number`. If I add the alias `AS [High Value]` the values are removed....

Comment: Please post the query, *uQuery Forecast/Orders*, as likely it too has underlying tables sharing *Part Number*.

Comment: I added the SQL above.

Comment: Is *Orders*, *Forecasts*, and *Builds* tables or queries themselves? If so, how does the union query render also with `[Orders].[Part Number]`?

Comment: BTW - union may be redundant here as you may be able to `LEFT JOIN` on all these tables with `GROUP BY`. Even better keep one *PartNumber* table with indicator field for orders, forecasts, builds as similar structures in db design means room for normalization and avoids complex queries.

Answer (score 0):

First, I'd recommend running a `Compact/Repair` operation on your database and validate integrity of your data. In my experience, a corrupt database may behave unexpectedly.

Secondly, Modify your `UNION` query to remove the `AS` statements from the first `SELECT`:

```
SELECT [Date], [Part Number], [Region] FROM Builds
UNION SELECT [Date], [Part Number], [Region] FROM Forecast
UNION SELECT [Date], [Part Number], [Region] FROM Orders;
```

I still believe you'll want only the `DISTINCT` results of your union query, as in this example:

```
SELECT u.DATE
    ,u.[Part Number]
    ,u.Region
    ,Val(IIf(IsNull(o.[QTY]), 0, o.[QTY])) AS [Order QTY]
    ,Val(IIf(IsNull(f.[QTY]), 0, f.[QTY])) AS [Forecast QTY]
    ,Val(IIf(IsNull(b.[QTY]), 0, b.[QTY])) AS [Build QTY]
FROM (
    (
        (SELECT DISTINCT [Date], [Part Number], [Region] from [uQuery Forecast/Orders]) AS u 
        LEFT JOIN Orders AS o ON (u.[Date] = o.[Date])
            AND (u.[Part Number] = o.[Part Number])
        ) LEFT JOIN Forecast AS f ON (u.[Date] = f.[Date])
        AND (u.[Part Number] = f.[Part Number])
    )
LEFT JOIN Builds AS b ON (u.[Date] = b.[Date])
    AND (u.[Part Number] = b.[Part Number]);
```

In order to display the result of each `QTY` on the same row, you will need the `DISTINCT` keyword in your union query to prevent multiple rows for the same `Product Number`/`Date` pair.

Comment: I've added my Union query's SQL if you need it. As for my IIf(), it's there to replace NULL values with 0. A good example is that I may have 100 of a part forecasted on 12/1, but nothing ordered or built. The IIf() takes those missing values, and fills it in with a 0.